# How to use Zero-Shot Learning on text?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Zero-shot learning used to predict the unseen classes using the attributes for each image.

For example, we feed the model pictures of horses and pandas. The model will learn how horses look like and what the difference between different colors. For the testing phase, if we give the model a picture of a zerba, it will be able to check the unseen classes and predict it correctly.

Recently, I got to know that Zero-shot can be used on text. But I am not sure how to create attributes for text and how does it work. There is not any helpful posts or links for Zero-shot learning on text.

Would you please explain it in a simple example or provide a helpful link for an article or a model for zeroshot learning on text.